# I am using Panels and in that i need one pane not to be shown on certain page. how can i do that?

Tags: panels

I am using Panels and in that i need one pane need not to show on certain page. how can i do that ?

I tried using visibility rule in Pane by using **String: Rule Path** but it is not working. Please help on how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Are you using them as blocks?

Comment: yes.. and i found it is working fine for one pane but if it is an injectable global region pane and if this has different panes then it is not working..

Comment: Can we done by using php code ?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if Panels' blocks are exported as regular blocks (can be found in `structure-> blocks in the admin menu) but if they can, blocks can be configured to appear/not appear on certain pages.

Comment: But i can't see those things in structure->blocks